# Get info about not installed SRU on solaris 11

Tags: solaris

I have registered repository on Solaris 11.4x86 VM. When I try to grab SRU I receive several results, one of them installed:

```
# pkg list -af entire
...
entire                    11.4-11.4.3.0.1.5.0        ---
entire                    11.4-11.4.2.0.1.3.0        i--
entire                    11.4-11.4.1.0.1.4.0        ---
entire                    11.4-11.4.0.0.1.15.0       ---
entire                    0.5.11-0.175.3.35.0.6.0    ---
...
```

For getting info about installed (11.4-11.4.2.0.1.3.0) I can use

```
# pkg info entire@11.4-11.4.2.0.1.3.0
and receive Summary, State, Packaging Date etc.
For not installed (all other instances) I receive:
# pkg info entire@11.4-11.4.3.0.1.5.0
pkg: info: no packages matching the following patterns you specified are
installed on the system.  Try querying remotely instead:
entire@11.4-11.4.3.0.1.5.0
```

My question is: how can I receive detailed info about all entire SRUs from list of available ones?

Or can you please tell me where can I read about this?

Comment: Found it.
By add -r option, it returns me the needed info:

# pkg info -r entire@11.4-11.4.2.0.1.3.0

Name: entire
          Summary: entire incorporation including Support Repository Update
                   (Oracle Solaris 11.4.2.3.0).
      Description: This package constrains system package versions to the same

Answer (score 2):

This command gets the needed info:

```
pkg info -r entire@11.4-11.4.2.0.1.3.0
```

Comment: Correct - `pkg info` without the `-r` flag only provides information on currently installed packages - the `-r` flag tells it to also query the package repository for info on packages/versions not currently installed.